# How to extract information after second comma in a string and remove what's in front of it?

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking to pull the city, province/state and country from a address field and I want to remove the business name and street name before as follows:

`addressName = "My Business, 123 Main Street, Vancouver, BC, Canada"`

I want to capture this:

`output = "Vancouver, BC, Canada"`

I have tried splitting the array using the comma as the entry point although in that case I only get one of the three pieces of information that I need and I have done so in order to capture just the business name in a separate field. Will I need to have a range for the array to go through? Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: `addressName.split(',').slice(2).join(',').trim()`

Comment: That makes sense, thank you very much!

Comment: You split using comma and remove the first two elements. Once again you join.

Comment: `"My Business, 123 Main Street, Vancouver, BC, Canada".replace(/(.+, )([^,]+,[^,]+,[^,]+)$/, '$2')` can do other fancy reg exp, this is just basic

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [`Array.prototype.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

```js
const addressName  = "My Business, 123 Main Street, Vancouver, BC, Canada";
const provinces = addressName.split(',').slice(2).join(',');
console.log(provinces);
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
var addressName = "My Business, 123 Main Street, Vancouver, BC, Canada"
var output = addressName.split(",").slice(2).join(",")
console.log(output)
```

Comment: *IDidn'tDownVote*, but it probably has something do do with code only answer, and the idea that's it's exactly the same as @Spectric's answer but 4 minutes slower. Also a snippet could somehow improve the answer if you've added some details. For more info, please check [answer].